# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) through jdbcTemplate

Tags: arrays, spring, maven, jdbctemplate

While updating data in database through spring jdbcTemplate, Please advise is there is any way so that I need not to hardcode the parameter Index,I am getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1408)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1421)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setNull(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1686)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setNull(StatementCreatorUtils.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:232)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:875)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
    at com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.dao.impl.JdbcPurchaseDAO.updateStock(JdbcPurchaseDAO.java:151)
    at com.ganeshTrading.riceAppService.controller.PurchaseController.updateStock(PurchaseController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Here, is my code:**

```
public void updateStock(Stock stock) {
        String sql = "update stock_details set ";
        Object[] obj = new Object[3];
        if(stock.getRemainingStock() != null) {
            sql+= "remaining_stock = ? ";
            obj[0] = stock.getRemainingStock();
            if(stock.getCommodityPricePerKg() != null) {
                sql+= ", commodityPricePerKg = ? ";
                obj[1] = stock.getCommodityPricePerKg();
                sql += " where commodity_id = ? ";
                obj[2] = stock.getCommodityId();
            }
            else {
                sql += " where commodity_id = ? ";
                obj[1] = stock.getCommodityId();
            }
        }
        else if(stock.getCommodityPricePerKg() != null) {
            sql+= " commodityPricePerKg = ? ";
            obj[0] = stock.getCommodityPricePerKg();
            sql += " where commodity_id = ? ";
            obj[1] = stock.getCommodityId();
        }
        if(jdbcTemplate == null)
            jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        System.out.println(obj.length);
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, obj);

    }
```

Please advise what is wrong in my code or there is some other way to do this through jdbcTemplate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print out the dynamic sql  you have created and see its correct or not.Seems Some issue with Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the number of parameters in the SQL statement doesn't match with the number of provided arguments. It is not obvious by looking at the code, but

```
Object[] obj = new Object[3];
obj[0] = "Duke";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, obj);
```

is basically the same as

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { "Duke", null, null });
```

JdbcTemplate assumes that the number of parameters in the SQL statement and in provided arguments array is the same.

To handle different number of arguments you can change from arrays to lists

```
List<Object> args = new ArrayList<>();
// some logic with args.add(...)
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args.toArray());
```

An alternative is the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("name", "Duke");

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE user SET name = :name", args);
```

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
sql+= " commodityPricePerKg = ? "
```

And:

```
sql+= ", commodityPricePerKg = ? ";
```

Are you sure your field in db is named like that? Maybe it is named "commodity_price_per_kg"?